# How to properly configure the after() function

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I wrote code that checks availability of sites.
And to change the status of sites after a user defined time put `after()` before the output function, but for some reason the status is updated before the specified time, what's wrong?
My goal is to enter time for each site (it can be different) and only after this time, the status is updated

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


data_list = []

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x700')
window.title("SiteChecker")


def set_input(obj, value):
    obj.delete(1.0, "END")
    obj.insert("END", value)




def SiteCheck():


    for data in data_list:
        url = data[0].get()
        status = data[2]
        if not str(url).startswith('http'):
            continue
        print(url)
        Get_Response = None
        try:
            Get_Response = requests.get(url)
        except:
            status.config(text='status bad')
            continue

        if Get_Response.status_code == 200:
            status.config(text='status ok')
            window.after(int(data[1].get()) * 1000, SiteCheck)

            pass

        else:
            status.config(text='status bad')
            window.after(int(data[1].get()) * 1000, SiteCheck)




def clicked():
    txt = Entry(window, width=18)
    txt.grid(column=0, pady=8)
    txt_row = txt.grid_info()['row']

    tim = Entry(window, width=3)
    tim.grid(row=txt_row, column=1, pady=8)
    txt_row = tim.grid_info()['row']

    result1 = Label(window, text="status")
    result1.grid(row=txt_row, column=2, pady=8)
    data_list.append([txt, tim, result1])


lbl1 = Label(window, text="Enter references:")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Enter the test time: ")
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl3 = Label(window, text="Availability status ")
lbl3.grid(column=2, row=1)

for loop in range(2, 6):
    txt1 = Entry(window, width=18)
    txt1.grid(column=0, row=loop, pady=8)

    tim1 = Entry(window, width=3)
    tim1.grid(column=1, row=loop, pady=8)

    result1 = Label(window, text="status")
    result1.grid(column=2, row=loop, pady=8)
    data_list.append([txt1, tim1, result1])

btn = Button(window, text="Add another site", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

Check_Button = Button(
    window,
    command=SiteCheck,
    text='Start checking',
)
Check_Button.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to delay the status update, for example 5 seconds, if the URL response can be received within second.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to create a dictionary as a global variable that stores details for each site listed `site_ref`, then you could split up the `SiteCheck` function into two separate functions, one that is called when the user presses the the `Check_Button` button and another that controls the timed intervals and updating the status message.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


data_list = []

site_ref = {}  # stores details for each site

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x700')
window.title("SiteChecker")


def set_input(obj, value):
    obj.delete(1.0, "END")
    obj.insert("END", value)



def check_status(url):  
    """this is the callback function that sends the request and 
       updates the status then it reschedules itself
    """
    time = site_ref[url]["time"]      # get details from `site_ref`
    status = site_ref[url]["status"]
    try:
        Get_Response = requests.get(url)
    except:
        status.config(text="status bad")
        return
    if Get_Response.status_code == 200:
        status.config(text="status ok")
    else:
        status.config(text='status bad')
    # reschedule call to callback
    window.after(time*1000, site_ref[url]["func"])

def SiteCheck():
    """This function is triggered by button and collects information 
       about each site, and schedules the first status check only.
    """
    for data in data_list:
        url = data[0].get()
        if not str(url).startswith('http'):
            continue
        time = int(data[1].get())
        status = data[2]
        site_ref.setdefault(url,  # use the url as the key for dictionary
            {"time": time,        # store the interval
             "func": lambda x=url: check_status(x), # store callback function
             "status": status})                     # store the status widget
        # then schedule the first call to the callback function
        window.after(time * 1000, site_ref[url]["func"])  

def clicked():
    txt = Entry(window, width=18)
    txt.grid(column=0, pady=8)
    txt_row = txt.grid_info()['row']

    tim = Entry(window, width=3)
    tim.grid(row=txt_row, column=1, pady=8)
    txt_row = tim.grid_info()['row']

    result1 = Label(window, text="status")
    result1.grid(row=txt_row, column=2, pady=8)
    data_list.append([txt, tim, result1])


lbl1 = Label(window, text="Enter references:")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Enter the test time: ")
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl3 = Label(window, text="Availability status ")
lbl3.grid(column=2, row=1)

for loop in range(2, 6):
    txt1 = Entry(window, width=18)
    txt1.grid(column=0, row=loop, pady=8)

    tim1 = Entry(window, width=3)
    tim1.grid(column=1, row=loop, pady=8)

    result1 = Label(window, text="status")
    result1.grid(column=2, row=loop, pady=8)
    data_list.append([txt1, tim1, result1])

btn = Button(window, text="Add another site", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

Check_Button = Button(
    window,
    command=SiteCheck,
    text='Start checking',
)
Check_Button.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```